# Print error in console without date and time using log4j

Tags: java, logging, log4j

Will it be possible to just print the error message in console using log4j without including date, time and severity details.

Log 4j.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
  <appender name="CONSOLE" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
  <param name="threshold" value="ERROR" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
              <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss,SSS} - %p | %m%n" />
        </layout>        
  </appender>

<logger name="package" >
    <level value="ERROR" />
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
</logger>

  <root>
        <priority value="ERROR" />
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
  </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

Comment: can you post your `log4j.properties` or `log4j.xml`? Of course it is possible, if you can post it I can start with an example and help you

Comment: did you try to remove those date pattern from your log4j.xml?

Answer (score 3):

You can check various ways of tweaking the output of log4j in [Pattern Layout](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html) . You could try using the following pattern layout to print only the message that has to be logged to console

```
   <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%m%n" />
```